In Azure Runbook - map a drive to remote server
I have a working PS Script to run in an Azure Runbook to map a drive to a remote server to then copy very specific files to Azure blob storage.
NOTE: The entire script works 100% in VSCode > Automation Runbook. It completes all steps as intended. However, when I publish the script and run the Runbook in the Portal, the code to map a drive, fails and therefore does not copy the files to blob storage. Overall, I need to 'get-childitem' to copy servername>share>subfolders>*.bak all subfolders to then copy specific files based on 'lastwritetime' (because there are multiple files in the dir with same *.bak ext.) to their respective folder name in blob.
I'm open to suggestions and really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance!
Here is the work performed to ensure PS remoting is enabled on remote Server.

Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name 'WINRM' | Select-Object -Property Name*
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name 'WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP' -RemoteAddress Any
restarted winrm service
Disabled remote server Firewall (to test)

The following was run on my local computer and also run in runbook which does look to have run successfully.

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'Target Server IP Address' -Concatenate

Note: My domain\username is member of Local Admin group on Remote Server
All the following snippets work in VSCode Azure Automation Runbook but does NOT work in the actual Azure Runbook.
snippet 1 to map drive result: The network path was not found.
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Source_Folder -Credential $Credentials -Scope Global
snippet 2 to map drive result: Access is denied. Connecting to remote server server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request.
NOTE: The Server is on the same Domain and I have local administrator and domain admin access.
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'remote server IP' -Concatenate -Force
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "" {New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\servername\share" -Credential $Credentials -Scope Global}
snippet 3 to map drive result: The network path was not found.
New-SmbMapping -LocalPath "Y:" -RemotePath "\servername\share" -UserName "domain\username" -Password "" -Persistent $true
snippet 4 to map drive result: System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.
Net Use Y: \servername\share /user:domain\username password /persistent:yes

There might be a couple of issues arises here when trying to map a drive to remote server.
Firstly, use credentialsunder shared resources in an automation account and store credentials instead of storing it directly in the script as detailed below.
Make sure that the necessary ports are free and available as these network restrictions may acts like access blockers.
You need to have a storage blob data contributor role to access the storage blob from an automation account. Check that you have a necessary permission to operate the tasks.
param (
    [string]$SourceFolder = "xxxx",
    [string]$containername = "newc",
    [string]$StorageAcc = "newaccsj",
    [string]$AccountKey = "RUH8i/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxDCtkgw7J5iXzT43G+ASt17Ca4A=="
)
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "newcred"
write-output "credential is $credential"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAcc -StorageAccountKey $AccountKey
write-output "context is $context"

Once it is retrieved, use below shown function script for copying the .bak files.
function Copy-Bak (
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "sourcepath" -Recurse -Filter *.bak | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) }
    
    foreach ($file in $allfiles) {
        $blobName = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($file.DirectoryName.Replace($Source, "").TrimStart("\"), $file.Name).Replace("\", "/")
        Write-Output "Uploading filePath"
        Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "containername" -Blob "blobName" -Context $context
    }
}
Copy-Bak -SourceFolder $SourceFolder -BlobContainer xxxx -StorageContext $context

Runbook published successfully:

You can also use Invoke-command to download and copy the files from one to another.

apologies, I should have and meant to add that I already have:


'credentials' under shared resources in the automation account


'storage blob data contributor' role to access the storage blob from an automation account as well.


I attempted and understand your function but, again, the issue is the script in Runbook cannot see the remote server. Unfortunately, I have read where some say you can do it and others say you cannot. link italic

Yes sometimes it depends on the type of server you are using. Have you also tried with Invoke command? @sllucas

After a ton of research, I managed to resolve my issue by installing Arc Server Extension on the remote Servers. With that, I am able to use map command: New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Source_Folder -Credential $Credentials -Scope Global. Then in (AA) Automation Account, I added the Arc Servers as Hybrid Workers. Also, in AA, I added an 'account' in Credentials for authentication. Keep in mind there are additional required Azure configurations to make all this work such as, Managed Identities, Key Vault Key/Access Policies and well as RBAC Roles/permissions. Thanks all!!
